# ViewPager + FragmentStatePagerAdapter : need to know when fragment is displayed (selected)

Tags: android, fragment, fragmentpageradapter

I am using a ViewPager plugged to a FragmentStatePagerAdapter. Each fragment contains a listview. In this listview I wish to display ads and make calls to a analytics server. I only want to make those calls when the user navigates to a fragment (so I cannot use the onCreateView or onActivityCreated events in the Fragment). Is there an event I can hook on to this end ?

**Update**
I realized that the way I am fetching my current fragment is flawe

```
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int page) {
      this.currentPage = page;
      tabsAdapter.getItem(page);
    }
```

`getItem(int position)` in the pager is actually responsible for instanciating the fragments, so it would create a new unattached fragment (hence `getActivity()` returning null). I think I will us an approach where I keep a map of the fragments (`<Position, Fragment>`), i will remove the fragment from the map when destoryItem is called in the pagerAdapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, best option is the second solution here:
http://tamsler.blogspot.nl/2011/11/android-viewpager-and-fragments-part-ii.html

so your thoughts are correct.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html

The `onPageSelected(int)` method sounds like it does what you want.

Comment: I tried this, but on this event if I try to launch my data tasks I need getActivity() for the context, getActivity() will return null

Comment: It would have been helpful if you had mentioned that requirement in the question :). Can you update with some sample code that illustrates the problem? I am somewhat surprised that onPageSelected would be called before onAttach (which is when getActivity() should stop returning null)